# OnItemLongClick on ExpandableListView crashes when a group is expanded

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I am working on an android project and making use of an ExpandableListView with a Custom ExpandableListAdapter.

I have an OnItemLongClickListener the the click handler should only be used when the group header is long pressed, any long clicks on the children should be ignored.

When all of the group headers are collapsed, the code works fine, when any group is expanded, even one I am not long clicking on, causes an exception to be thrown.

The stacktrace is a follows:

> 7452-7452/com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.DatabaseDetails
>               at com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.ConnectedDBManagerHost$1.onItemLongClick(ConnectedDBManagerHost.java:142)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2854)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2804)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Below is my code

```
mDrawerDBs.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(id) == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getGroupCount(); i++)
                {
                    ((DatabaseDetails)parent.getItemAtPosition(i)).setIsDefaultDatabase(false);
                }
                DatabaseDetails dbDetails = (DatabaseDetails)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ((DatabaseDetails) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).setIsDefaultDatabase(true);

                ConnectionsManager.connectedDatabase.put("database", Encryption.encrypt(((DatabaseDetails) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getDatabaseName()));

                QueryEditor queryFragment = (QueryEditor)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_queryEditor);
                queryFragment.setDatabaseUsed();
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.BoardiesITSolutions.MysqlManager.DatabaseDetails
```

You are trying to cast a String to DatabaseDetails and I guess it happens somewhere here:

```
((DatabaseDetails)parent.getItemAtPosition(i)).setIsDefaultDatabase(false);
```

Sometimes the item returned by `getItemAtPosition()` must be String otherwise this exception wouldn't be thrown. Just debug the click listener step by step until you figure out exactly where and why this Exception occurs and then fix it.

Comment: I know the issue is related to the casting, however, it doesn't make any sense why. My code works, until one of the groups are expanded it then breaks. I would of understood it if I was long pressing on the child which is just a string but I am pressing on the group